# Textbox check if there is a Letter | C#

Tags: c#, textbox, char, int

In my app i want to check if my textbox had a letter or that the number is higher then 20.

```
class AantalVragenChecker
    {
        public int AantalVragen
        { 
            get;
            set;
        }

        public void Check()
        {

            if (AantalVragen(char) || AantalVragen > 20)
            {
                throw new InvalidAantalVragenException(AantalVragen + "Bevat een verkeerd karakter of een cijfer hoger dan 20");
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is in this part:

```
if (AantalVragen(char)
```

Comment: `AantalVragen` is a property, not a method.

Comment: I fail to see where is the textbox and your syntax is wrong. What do you want to achieve with that `AantalVragen(char) `

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is something like:

```
class AantalVragenChecker
{
    public string AantalVragen { get; set; }

    public void Check()
    {
        int res;           

        if (!int.TryParse(AantalVragen, out res) || res > 20)
        {
            throw new InvalidAantalVragenException(AantalVragen + 
                "Bevat een verkeerd karakter of een cijfer hoger dan 20");
        }
    }
}
```